# What is a Mid Weight job?

Tags: job-description

My wife just encountered the term `mid weight` in several job advertisements that she was looking at.  This is not a term that either of us had heard before<sup>1</sup> but it appears to mean mid-level.

- Does this translate as `mid-level`?
- And/or are there other connotations?
- Is this a common expression elsewhere?

---

1. She was browsing jobs based in Australia, and I'm Australian and *still* had never heard of this term.

Comment: What industry? `mid weight` could be a popular term in some industries.

Comment: @SandraK She would be looking at copyright/editing and "wordy" related fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an industry specific term, as a Google search for "mid-weight job" returns ads mostly for (graphic) designer jobs, or advertising and publishing jobs.

It is roughly the equivalent of a mid-level (insert title here), but with a very [narrow band of experience](http://www.designtalkboard.com/design-articles/graphic-designers.php) between junior and senior. I suspect this is because many designers quickly move into higher roles like art director or producer.

It also seems to be a term that has been [in use in the USA](https://designcareer.wordpress.com/tag/becoming-a-middleweight-designer/) for a while and is now being adopted by the industry in Australia.

Comment: Middleweight is also used in the UK - btw art director is a v senior role normaly